# What is a name for this "plate" scrolling functionality?

Tags: design-patterns, scrolling

The Google Ventures website at http://www.googleventures.com/ has interesting functionality -- when you scroll down the page, the upper "masthead" stays fixed to the window but is slowly covered up by the content below.

This is somewhat similar to parallax scrolling, but usually that involves multiple layers moving at varying speeds. In this case only one piece is moving.

Is this an established design pattern that has been named and used elsewhere? The best name my team could think of is "tectonic plates" but I doubt that is common terminology.

Thanks!

Comment: On my iPad, i cannot see the effect you describe on that google site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all practical purposes it is termed the "Collapsing Header Effect" (genius, right?) and you can find out more and how to implement it yourself [here](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-collapsing-header-effect).

EDIT

The idea is fairly new as far as I know and its simply an "effect" rather than a pattern. I cant recall where else I have seen it but it is becoming more common.

The article will tell you that this effect is achieved using a fixed position header and a relative position content `<div>`. This creates the subduction effect you mentioned withtectonic plates.

I hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: +1 For the reference article...Don't we have enough names for the same concepts in this industry? Cinemagraph (animated gif) being my latest favorite. But, fair enough, and to each their own one what we call things. :)

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a rare technique but it's helpful to see it documented and named somewhere.

Comment: +1 for adding the edit so that the article's content is summarized and will still be here in case of link rot.

Answer (score 4):

It's a variation on a fixed header/footer - however, instead of the header of footer remaining static while the content move *under* them, this execution has it the other way - wherein the header/footer remains static while the content flows *over* them.

Re: Parallax
In animation terms it's multiplane animation but, for web (computer science) we call it parallax scrolling. The main difference between the two - besides name - is that with multiplane animation, the plates move while the camera remains stationary. In parallax, the camera moves (scrolling) and the plates move.

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplane_camera

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling

Comment: +1 Yes, it's basically a *sticky header*, but while most sticky headers are on top of the scrolling content, this one is underneath the scrolling content.

Comment: @obelia - thanks for the confirming comment, edited answer as I believe it is more accurate.

Comment: Thanks guys! It is similar to a sticky header, but it doesn't do one of the main things a sticky header does, which is make site navigation constantly visible.

Comment: @MichaelHisten I disagree that part of the sticky header construct is to make the navigation stick, but to each their own.

Comment: Josh, not to get on a tangent, but I'm not sure how you can separate the concept a sticky header from navigation -- it seems the primary use case/argument in favor of making something sticky is because it allows quick access to navigation:   http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/11/sticky-menus-are-quicker-to-navigate/

Comment: @MichaelHisten - Indeed, but not really a tangent, we're still on topic (luckily they only show a few comments before hiding them). I see the argument - do not get me wrong. Having said that, a header is the top of the document/page. Sticky, in this context, is equivalent to static. So, even with the "collapsing" header (which actually doesn't collapse, it is covered by the content), uses a "sticky header"...if it actually collapsed (shrank in height) as the name implies, okay. The article is specifically about sticky navigation (in the header or not). But that's semantics.